# Which framework for HTML5 mobile web app?

Tags: web-development, mobile, web-framework, cross-platform, html5

I used to be an iPhone app developer. Now there are frequent enquires on cross-platform mobile app. So I look for a web based solution and find [Sencha Touch](http://www.sencha.com/products/touch/). Are there more options? What's your experience and comment on these frameworks? Thanks!

Comment: This post on StackOverflow is basically the same question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3031643/resources-frameworks-for-mobile-development-iphone-android-using-html5

Answer (score 4):

The best ones I've seen so far that incorporate web technology (and with which you should have no trouble using Sencha):

- http://www.phonegap.com/
- http://www.appcelerator.com/

What I like of Appcelerator Titanium is that I can also use PHP/Python/Ruby in very fancy ways, however and unfortunately they don't support as much platforms as I wish they would (they've been in Blackberry closed beta for like forever).

Answer (score 1):

I whould suggest to pay close attention to [jQueryMobile project](http://jquerymobile.com/). Though it is still in alpha stage it has serious roadmap and some big names as sponsors, that should guarantee open nature of the code in long run.

P.S. Sencha/EXT JS have some not nice history if license inconsistency.

Comment: Now it's in its 4th alpha and it's still as buggy as the first version. I'm sure they'll iron out kinks eventually but I've seen very little progress over the past several months.

Comment: Based on my experience with EXTjs and personal knowledge with web technology in general, I would not trust anything from Sencha. EXTjs has been a long drawn out, multi-version trainwreck. I like jQuery core but I would research jq-mobile carefully before using it. They started out solving styling inconsistencies with JavaScript and that was enough to write them off for me. Also, people continue to blame jq mobile for phonegap getting a rep for less than optimal performance.

Answer (score 1):

I did not try developing mobile web applications before but I have tried GWT and I like it's architecture very much and it seems to support what you want : http://code.google.com/p/gwt-mobile-webkit/ IMO, you should give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

I have not had a chance to dive into the unify project yet but i have with phonegap and by looking at the project you just cant go wrong.

http://unify.github.com/unify/

Uses the following open source projects and combines them;

- Phone gap (application wrapper)
- Qooxdoo (js framework)
- Adobe air
- Sass (css extension)

I can only assume 4 projects are better than one so combining the various cross-platform mobile web solutions into one project should make for better looking native applications. But as i said i havent developed into it yet but i am looking too in the near future, so it seems worth a shot thought i would mention it because it dont seem to be well known.

Comment: were you ever able to use this in a project? How did it respond?